# how to view background logs of a firefox extension on Android?

Tags: android, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am debugging a firefox extension for android. I have latest firefox nightly build installed in both Windows PC and phone. I connect my phone to Windows, and go to about:debugging on Windows. I can see my phone device there and my extension in extension list, but when I click "Inspect" button of my extension, I cannot see logs printed in background.js showing in Console tab. I call console.log in first line of backgrond.js and I am sure it is executed.
BTW I can see console.log printing logs from content scripts.

Comment: Enable "multiprocess" option in the console toolbar.

Comment: I could not find multiprocess option in console toobar, but I found "Multiprocess Toolbox" at bottom of extension list. When I click "Inspect" in it, I can see logs from all extensions in console tab, how can I filter logs for my extension?